# Firebird 2.5 permission denied on Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: permissions, firebird, firebird2.5, folder-permissions

I'm having a problem trying to create databases with Firebird on my Xubuntu 16.04 (fresh) installation.
I have the directory /media/foo/databases/ where I want to put my databases files.

When I try to create the database in that directory, I get the following error:

(from `isql-fb`):

```
SQL> create database 'localhost:/media/foo/databases/database.fdb' user 'SYSDBA' password 'masterkey';
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 08001
I/O error during "open O_CREAT" operation for file "/media/foo/databases/database.fdb"
-Error while trying to create file
-Permission denied
```

(from `flamerobin`):

```
*** IBPP::SQLException ***
Context: Database::Create
Message: isc_dsql_execute_immediate failed

SQL Message : -902
Unsuccessful execution caused by a system error that precludes successful execution of subsequent statements

Engine Code    : 335544344
Engine Message :
I/O error during "open O_CREAT" operation for file "/media/foo/databases/database.fdb"
Error while trying to create file
Permission denied
```

`ls -ld` of that folder outputs:  `drwxrwx--- 2 firebird firebird 4096 Out 21 22:55` which matches [this page](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq39/) of Firebird's FAQ.

`ps ax | grep firebird` outputs:

```
`  940 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/fbguard -daemon -forever -pidfile /var/run/firebird/2.5/fbserver.pid`
```

---

Here are a couple of things I have already tried:

- Running `isql-fb` as sudo
- Running `su firebird` and then `isql-fb`
- Running flamerobin as sudo
- Adding myself to the firebird group (``` adduser ``id -un`` firebird ```)

---

**UPDATE**

After running `apt-get upgrade` and reinstalling firebird2.5-superclassic, I now can create and connect to databases using `isql-fb`, even without root. **Flamerobin, however, still can't connect or create** the databases because of permission denied.